# Close Open Menu Before Animating Another

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu, menu

I am experimenting, and still finding the best way to go about this. I have multiple dropdown menus. I am trying to check for other open menus, close them, and then run the animation on the clicked menu, or simply close the menu clicked on if it is already open. Here is what I have thus far.

```
$('ul.primary li').click(function(event) {
            if ($(this).children('ul.drop').is(':visible')) {
                $(this).children('ul.drop').slideUp(function() {
                    $(this).parent('li').removeClass('active');
                });
            }
            else if ($(this).siblings().children('ul.drop').is(':visible')) {
                        $(this).siblings().children('ul.drop').slideUp(function() {
                            $(this).parent('li').removeClass('active');
                        });
                        $(this).children('ul.drop').slideDown(function() {
                            $(this).parent('li').addClass('active');
                        });
            }
            else {
                $(this).children('ul.drop').slideDown(function() {
                    $(this).parent('li').addClass('active');
                });
            }
        });
```

Edit: I cannot figure out how to make the open drop-down animate closed BEFORE the clicked on drop-down animates open. JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/JG9dB/

Comment: What is your question. If you're looking for a code review then try http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Can you set up a fiddle with the markup. It'll make it easier for us to work with and visualize.

Comment: Sorry about the lack of explanation. The problem is, i can't figure out how to make the open menu animate closed before the next one opens. JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/JG9dB/

Comment: Perhaps "How can I make the menu that was clicked wait to open, until after the other menu's close animation is completed?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I would go about it....

JAVASCRIPT:

```
$('ul.primary>li').click(function(event) {
  var li = $(this);
  var liOld = $('ul.active').parents("li");

  if($('ul.active').length!=0){
      $('ul.active').removeClass('active').slideUp('slow', function(){
        if(li.index() != liOld.index()){
           li.children('ul.drop').slideDown('slow').addClass('active');
        }
      });
  }
  else{
     $(this).children('ul.drop').slideDown('slow').addClass('active');
  }
});
```

DEMO:
http://jsfiddle.net/JG9dB/35/

This should take care of the problem.  Let me know if you have any other questions!

Comment: Works well! Is there a way to slow this down so it is more apparent? Something akin to this: http://www.knapheide.com/

Comment: Yeah, of course! In the slideup/slidedown functions, you can replace the 'fast'/'medium' with a number. This option is for the duration and it controls the animation length (in milliseconds). Also please refer to the changes I made to my original post. Hope this helps!

Comment: I slowed it down in an attempt, but it seems that one menu closes as the other opens, versus closing before firing the event to open the next. Which is what im trying to accomplish.

Comment: I am terribly sorry! I made the changes to my initial post. This will guarantee that all siblings will slide up BEFORE sliding down!